# MeshLint addon for Blender 2.90

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am working on booleans of meshes which is intermittently failing. I came across [MeshLint addon](https://github.com/SavMartin/meshlint-Update-to-2.80) on a different Q&A. I have installed `curve edit tools` addon before, which was straightforward. In the case of `MeshLint`, I cant seem to get it working on my 2.91 (and also on a 2.80 that I have installed alongside). I tried installing from `User Preferences` -> `Addons` -> `Install from file...` -> `__init__.py`. I have also tried putting the repo folder into `scripts` folder. Neither of them makes `MeshLint` to appear as an option in the available addons list so that I can enable it. I would really like to have this addon to identify issues in my mesh. What am I doing wrong in installing this addon or is there an alternative option?

Thank you for your time

PS: I have tried `Select By Trait`, `Clean up` options natively available but would still like to have MeshLint.

Comment: Since this is a single file addon, recommend download `__init__.py` , rename it to `meshlint.py` then install from file, or copy into `scripts/addons/` folder.   The other option is make a `meshlint` folder in your `scripts/addons` folder and copy `__init__.py` to `scripts/addons/meshlint/__init__.py`  Possibly the worst filename for an addon that is not in its own folder is `__init__.py`.

Comment: I believe that renaming file was probably what was missing in what I was doing. Now it works on my 2.91. Mind posting your comment as an answer? I will be happy to mark it as an answer.